# Expire-date in refresh-token (oauth2, exact)

Tags: oauth-2.0, exact-online

So I'm using the exact-online XML-api to retrieve some user-related data.
This works fine so far, but since it is using oauth 2.0, I am being redirected after 600 sec and the login-prompt appears again.

This function refreshes the access-token:

```php
/**
 * @param string $refreshToken
 * @return array {access_token, expires_in, refresh_token}
 */
public function refreshAccessToken($refreshToken)
{
    $params = array(
        'refresh_token' => $refreshToken,
        'grant_type' => self::GRANT_REFRESH_TOKEN,
        'client_id' => $this->clientId,
        'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret
    );

    $url = sprintf(self::URL_TOKEN, $this->countryCode);
    return $this->getResponse($url, $params);
}
```

I debuged into it and the *expires_in* is set to 600. I guess this is the cause I'm being logged after after a short amount. My question: how can I disable this 600 sec timeout?

Also I found this function:

```php
/**
 * @param int $expiresInTime
 */
protected function setExpiresIn($expiresInTime)
{
    $this->expiresIn = time() + $expiresInTime;
}
```

I modified the function and added a ***1000** so it doesn't run out, but that didn't affect the outcome.

Is this an oauth-specific thing? Is it somehow managable to don't be kicked off after 10 mins?

There is no such thing in the backend of exact-online, which could change this value. Also, since this is a request I recieve, I don't think I can manipulate it, right?

---

**Update 1** 
Due to the good feedback, I think I got a start with that problem, but no solution yet. I'll provide the code I'm currently using. I also asked the support of exact, but didn't got too much help there unfortunatly.

Please see this code:

```php
<?php
require_once($sShopHomeDir . "modules/" . $sModulePath . "/library//exact/ExactApi.php");
$this->_exactApi = new ExactApi('de', $this->_sClientId, $this->_sClientSecret, $this->_sDivision);
$this->_exactApi->getOAuthClient()->setRedirectUri($this->_sRedirectUri.$param);

if (!isset($_GET['code']))
{
    // Redirect to Auth-endpoint
    $authUrl = $this->_exactApi->getOAuthClient()->getAuthenticationUrl();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl, true, 302);
    die('Redirect');
}
else
{
    $tokenResult = $this->_exactApi->getOAuthClient()->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
    $this->_exactApi->setRefreshToken($tokenResult['refresh_token']);
}
```

From the comments and answer, I'm convinced that this is the way to go. I'm retrieving a code and store/set the refresh-token - which, from my understanding, is correct that way.

For a better readabilty, I'll provide links to the two files which Exact online provides in their examples:

[ExactApi.php](http://pastebin.com/7SungXKZ)

[ExactOAuth.php](http://pastebin.com/DruRgqRe)

Comment: The site developers.exactonline.com describes the available flows. Continue the flow steps to get a longer lasting token (1 year normally) or start the oauth flow over to get another 10 minutes.

Comment: Do not forget that the flow can include additional steps such as digitoken or two phase authentication.

Comment: Well, I was on the demanded site. I even got my "basic setup" from here. But I can't find anything related to the expiration-date. Regardless, thanks for the help, i'll dig into that once again. Maybe I just oversaw it.

Comment: Hi @DasSaffe, did the answer fix your issue? What is needed to get you connected?

Comment: I'm still on it, trying to get an example from exact with this flow, but couldn't manage to get a "lifetime"-key so far. Will keep you updated.

Comment: The expiration date has been lifted a few months ago. All OAuth permissions are now always valid.

Comment: Maybe I'm totally wrong here, but I'm still not able to get a permanent token. I'll update the question now with the current code I have.

Answer (score 1):

You have two OAuth flows supported by Exact Online. From the information and the timeout you give I am pretty sure you are using the implicit grant flow, which is not documented by Exact, but it does work.

The only other option you have is to use the [token based authentication flow](https://developers.exactonline.com/#Implementation.html%3FTocPath%3DSecurity%7CAuthorization%2520(Oauth%25202)%7C_____1), which requires an extra step, namely exchanging your response code for an access token. That token is valid for a year and can be refreshed afterwards to extend the period for another year. The token based authentication flow is only useful in environments you can control, like web applications.

That token based authentication flow doesn't work with two phase authentication, so you can't refresh a token after that one year period.

Comment: this is what I'm currently using, but still I'm being stuck with the login-form again. I'll provide more information in my question now